# Plotly not showing graph correctly

Tags: python, plotly-python

First I had code that color coded the line graphs, but didn't display the values correctly:
[Graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6DQE.png)
Then, I got rid of the color aspect and ran it, which ended up working for me:
[Graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0oDQ.png)

However then, the graph added a random 5th line that I'm not sure where it came from and I'd like to add back color coding but I'm not sure how.

Comment: First of all, the value of the Y axis in the first graph is a string, so we need to change it to a number. Also, in the next graph, you can add the category name to the color to make it color-coded. `fig = px.line(df_long, x='Year', y='value', color='your_category_name')`

Comment: Yes, but color = variable does color code the lines, but it messes up the display of the plot

Comment: Secondly, this data was manually inputted, what could be a string?

Comment: I can't answer this question because I don't understand how it is disturbed. Have you noticed that the order of the first Y axis is disjointed?

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why it does that... But when I remove the colors then it shows it correctly